# NuxtJS with Vuetify tabs using dynamic routes not re-rendering page

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have page that has v-tabs using the nuxt attribute, each tab directs to a dynamic route

cars/_brand_name/index.vue (making the _brand_name a mandatory parameter)

When I load the page /cars/bmw: mounted get's called successfully but after switching to other tabs the URL updates correctly but the page no longer re-renders, mounted no longer getting called.

Am I missing some part of the lifecycle? Should I be watching the route param and force the page to reload? I don't remember needing to do this with Vue alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often caused when the route component is the same as previous route. The best way to force Vue to re-render the page is to set a `:key` attribute on the router with a unique value, it is common to use `$route.fullPath`.

Update your router view like so.

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't find this anywhere!

Comment: This did seem to be the problem for me too. Only Nuxt isn't using <router-view> but <Nuxt /> adding the key in this component didn't fix it. So I decided to go for /item/:id instead of /items/:id. (/items/ being the parent)